# Saving and loading data from a form without submitting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've been tasked with writing a load/save function for a rather large form.  This way the user can save their work and then come back later and load it and continue to work.

I've decided to use Server side storage and save the data locally to a mysql database.    I figured out the 'saveForm', it simply stores $_POST as a long string into column.

I can't figure out how to write the 'loadForm'.

I have:

```
<form id="qa" .. "> 
    <button id="saveForm" type="submit"..."> 
    <button id="loadForm" type="submit"..."> 
    <input type="hidden" id="unique_user_id"..."> 
</form>

<javascript> 
$('#saveForm').bind({
    click: function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post',
            url: "/saveForm.php",
            data: $("#qa").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("form was submitted");
            },
        });
        return false;
    },
}); 
<javascript>


saveForm.php:  (PHP & PDO) 
// connect
insert into `saveQAForm` ($_POST['id'],var_export($_POST));
```

Comment: When the page is loaded ($(document).ready()), the loadForm function is executed: an AJAX request is sent to the server and it responses with data to fill the form. In this case, the server has to query the database and return the requested data. You can do this without submitting anything.

Comment: Users actually need to click on a button to load the form data?

Comment: Yes, there is a "load" and "save" which they can use or not, up to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#loadForm').bind({
       click: function() {
          $.ajax({ 
             type: 'post',
             url: "/loadForm.php",
             data: 'id=123&token=8ash198hkuhd98yhk',
             success: function(data) {
                $('#first_name').val = data.first_name;
                $('#last_name').val = data.last_name;   
             }
          });
          return false;
       },
    }); 

});
```

**loadForm.php**

```
// Get values
$id = $_POST['id'];
$token = $_POST['token'];

// Check hash value here. Use your preferred
// database method ensuring POST values are filtered first. Then:
if($token == $row['token'])
{
   // Make DB query to get form data and return it as JSON
   return json_encode($row);
}
```

I feel it is important to pass a unique token or nonce that is unique to the user/session when retrieving the form so that another person couldn't make a request for an ID and get that user's personal information. Just a thought.

Comment: This worked great.  I didn't have to do the token since it's already part of the form data but everything else look good.  I'll try it and post the final solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is loaded ($(document).ready()), the loadForm function is executed: an AJAX request is sent to the server and it responses with data to fill the form. In this case, the server has to query the database and return the requested data. You can do this without submitting anything.

Here's an example:

**Client-side:**

```
$(document).ready (loadForm);

function loadForm () {
  $.ajax ({
    url: '/loadForm.php' ,
    success: function (data) {
      $('#firstField').val (data.firstField);
      $('#secondField').val (data.secondField);
    }
  });
```

**Server-side:** query the database and echo the data

Answer (score 0):

You can load the saved data (if any) during the execution of php code and fill in these data fields in your form. Ajax here may not be necessary.

```
<?php //yourform.php (PHP & PDO) 
// connect
select * from `saveQAForm` where user_id = $_COOKIE['user_id']

?><input name="field1" value="<?=(isset($data['field1'])?$data['field1']:""?>" />
```